# How to add new route in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel,

this is my issue, I downloaded latest laravel 5.2 using composer and run initial code using wamp, it runs without any issue. Now I want to add a simple about us page. So I put href in **welcome.blade.php**

```
<a href="{{ url('aboutus') }}">About Us</a>
```

After that I changed the **route.php** as below:

```
Route::get ( '/', function () {
return view ( 'welcome' );
} );

Route::get ( '/aboutus', function () {
    return view ( 'welcome' );
} );


Route::group ( [ 
        'middleware' => [ 
                'web' 
        ] 
], function () {

} );
```

I just added the "aboutus" route part, but when I click the **About Us** link, server gives a `404 error`, please help me.

Comment: Make sure the url is `yoursite/aboutus` and not `yoursite/directory/aboutus` first and possibly try `Route::get("/aboutus", function(){
   return View::make("welcome");
});`

Comment: Can you check the results of `php artisan route:list` that its showing up in there?

Comment: "mysite/public" is the my main page - its working fine , after the clicking href link is "mysite/public/aboutus"

Comment: @MarkDavidson  its give two URI "/" & "aboutus"

Comment: @Matt i did the your changes but same result 404 error

Comment: Is mod rewrite enabled on your wamp install?

Comment: @lamzozo its disabled, shell i enable it ?

Comment: @lamzozo , after the enabling the  mod rewrite its working fine thanks

Comment: And Mark & Matt thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

```
Use Route::get ( 'aboutus', function () {
    return view ( 'welcome' );
} );
```

Please check this.

Comment: as per the lamzozo enabled the mod rewrit so now issue is fixed. Thanks